# How can I edit functionality in Moodle in the 'Restrict Access' section for an assignment?

Tags: moodle

[image: Here is the section moodle I'm talking about]

I want to change the text field under the "choose.." to a drop down. I'm under the impression that I need to make this change in the Availability folder in moodle?

Comment: you'll need to give more precision :
If you're asking about moodle administration this won't be the right place. (go to the official community forum)
If you're writing a plugin it'd be good to share some of your code and what you tried so far.

Comment: @Veterini Essentially all I want to do is change the text field to a drop down. I don't even know where to find the html for it. I think its suppose to be under the Availability folder. Could you specify which details or additional information would help to clarify my question further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the string

First go to Site admin > Development > Debugging

And switch on "Show origin of languages strings" (debugstringids)

And save changes

Then go to the assignment and add `?strings=1` or `&strings=1` to the url

This will display the string id and component of every string

eg:

[image: Screenshot of the restrict access popup in Moodle with the string ids displayed]

So the string id is `choosedots` and the component is `moodle`

To change the text of the string, it is advisable to do this through language customisation rather than development.

Go to Site admin > Language > Language customisation > [Choose language] > Open language for customisation

Then search for Component = `Moodle.php` and String identifier = `choosedots`

You can then change the text - this is a core Moodle string though, so beware that this will change the string everywhere not just in the assignment activity

[image: Screenshot of the language customisation screen in Moodle]

Answer (score 0):

Please go to your Moodle folder > open lang folder > open en(if you are using any other language open that folder) folder > open moodle.php in any editor > search for "choosedots" and change the text as per your choice.
Here is the line

```
$string['choosedots'] = 'Choose...';
```